# Android listview scroll slowly with large size bitmap images

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I read the facebook developer blog:https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-android/10151189598933920

It said they were using a Custom ListView Recycler to speed up the scrolling performance. Right now the facebook native Android app works very well in terms of scrolling and viewing large images.

I am wondering how to write your own customized ListView Recycler? I am using a ViewHolder.

Here is my ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CampusWallArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CampusWallModel> {
    private final List<CampusWallModel> list;
    
    class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView ivThumb;
        public TextView display_name;
        public ImageView **ivImage**;
        public ImageView ivImageBackground;
        public TextView time;
        public TextView message;
        public Button bComment;
        public Button bLike;
        public Button bMore;
        public ImageView ivRedDot;
        public ProgressBar pbLoading;
        public RelativeLayout bg;
    }

    public CampusWallArrayAdapter(Context context, List<CampusWallModel> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.campuswallrow, list);
        this.list = list;
    }
    
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.campuswallrow, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivThumb);
            holder.display_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            **holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);**
            holder.ivImageBackground = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImageBackground);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            holder.bComment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bComment);
            holder.bLike = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bLike);
            holder.bMore = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bMore);
            holder.ivRedDot = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivRedDot);
            holder.pbLoading = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);
            holder.bg = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bg);
                
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        
        //final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            
            holder.pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ivThumb.setImageBitmap(null);
            holder.ivThumb.setImageDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.avatar));
            **holder.ivImage.setImageBitmap(null);**
            holder.ivImageBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            holder.time.setText("");
            holder.message.setText("");
            holder.bLike.setText("");
            holder.bComment.setText("");
            holder.bComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_comment);
            holder.display_name.setText("");
            holder.bLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.bLike.setClickable(true);
            holder.bLike.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.dimgrey3));
            holder.bLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_like);
            holder.ivRedDot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.bMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            
            if (list.get(position).display_name == null){
                holder.pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.bLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.bLike.setClickable(false);
                holder.bComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.bComment.setClickable(false);
            } else {
                holder.bLike.setTypeface(Fonts.getOpenSansBold(v.getContext()));
                holder.bLike.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).likes));
                if (list.get(position).user_like == -1 || list.get(position).user_like == 0){
                    holder.bLike.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            list.get(position).likes++;
                            list.get(position).user_like = 1;
                            holder.bLike.setClickable(false);
                            holder.bLike.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).likes));
                            holder.bLike.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.white1));
                            holder.bLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_liked);
                            Log.i("like thread invalid", "yes");
                            listView.invalidateViews();
                            
                            // ---------------------- new api for campus wall like ---------------------------------
                            new likeThread(list.get(position).school_thread_id).start();
                        }
                    }); 
                } else if (list.get(position).user_like == 1){
                    holder.bLike.setClickable(false);
                    holder.bLike.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.white1));
                    holder.bLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_liked);
                }
                
                if (list.get(position).thumb_bitmap != null){
                    holder.ivThumb.setImageDrawable(null);
                    holder.ivThumb.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).thumb_bitmap);
                    
                    holder.ivThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (!list.get(position).is_anonymous){
                                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                                extras.putInt("user_id", list.get(position).user_id);
                                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), OthersProfile.class);
                                i.putExtras(extras);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                    });                 
                } 
                
                if (list.get(position).is_anonymous){
                    holder.display_name.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.black1));
                } else {
                    holder.display_name.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.blue0));
                }
                holder.display_name.setTypeface(Fonts.getOpenSansBold(v.getContext()));
                holder.display_name.setText(list.get(position).display_name);
                holder.display_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!list.get(position).is_anonymous){
                            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                            extras.putInt("user_id", list.get(position).user_id);
                            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), OthersProfile.class);
                            i.putExtras(extras);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                
                if (list.get(position).image_url != null){
                    holder.pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    
                    if (picWidth > 0){
                        int y = picWidth/2;
                        if (imageBg == null){
                            imageBg = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), NinePatch.getNinePatch(R.drawable.backgroundimage, picWidth, y, v.getContext()));
                        }
                        holder.ivImageBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(imageBg);
                    }
                    
                    if (list.get(position).bitmap != null){
                        if (picWidth > 0){
                            holder.pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            **holder.ivImage.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).RecBitmap);**
                            
                            if (!list.get(position).loaded){
                                //holder.ivImage.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade)); //Set animation to your ImageView
                                list.get(position).loaded = true;
                            }                           
                        }
                        
                        holder.ivImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //Log.i("getWidth", String.valueOf(list.get(position).bitmap.getWidth()) + "/" + String.valueOf((double) picWidth/list.get(position).bitmap.getWidth()));
                                OohlalaMain.tabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                rlBigImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                //tvWords.setText(list.get(position).message);
                                if (list.get(position).bitmap != null){
                                    ivBigImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(list.get(position).bitmap, picWidth, (int) (((double) picWidth/list.get(position).bitmap.getWidth())*list.get(position).bitmap.getHeight()), false));           
                                    rlBigImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            OohlalaMain.tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            rlBigImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    pbImageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                                /*
                                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                                extras.putString("image_url", list.get(position).image_url);
                                extras.putString("image_words", list.get(position).message);
                                extras.putInt("picWidth", picWidth);
                                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), CampusWallImage.class);
                                i.putExtras(extras);
                                startActivity(i);
                                */
                            }
                        }); 
                    } else {    
                        if (picWidth > 0){
                            list.get(position).loaded = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    holder.ivImageBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                }
                
                holder.time.setTypeface(Fonts.getOpenSansLightItalic(v.getContext()));
                holder.time.setText(list.get(position).added_time);
                holder.message.setTypeface(Fonts.getOpenSansRegular(v.getContext()));
                holder.message.setText(list.get(position).message);
                
                holder.bComment.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).comment_count));
                holder.bComment.setTypeface(Fonts.getOpenSansBold(v.getContext()));
                holder.bComment.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                        extras.putInt("school_thread_id", Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).school_thread_id));
                        extras.putInt("thread_type", thread_type);
                        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), CampusWallComment.class);
                        i.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivity(i);
                        
                        if (list.get(position).num_unread_comments > 0){
                            list.get(position).num_unread_comments = 0;
                            holder.ivRedDot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.bComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_comment);
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                
                if (list.get(position).num_unread_comments > 0){
                    holder.bComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_comment_unread);
                    holder.ivRedDot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                
                //Log.i("display thread: ", rowView.toString());
                
                if (Profile.userId != list.get(position).user_id){
                    holder.bMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                holder.bMore.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (Profile.userId == list.get(position).user_id){
                            showAlertDialog(list.get(position).school_thread_id);
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                
                holder.bg.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                        extras.putInt("school_thread_id", Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).school_thread_id));
                        extras.putInt("thread_type", thread_type);
                        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), CampusWallComment.class);
                        i.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivity(i);
                        
                        if (list.get(position).num_unread_comments > 0){
                            list.get(position).num_unread_comments = 0;
                            holder.ivRedDot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.bComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_comment);
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            
            }

            return convertView;
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(final String thread_id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
        alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.Delete_Thread));
        alert.setMessage(getString(R.string.Warning_This_cannot_be_undone));
        alert.setButton(getString(R.string.No), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        alert.setButton2(getString(R.string.Yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                RestClient result = null;
                try {
                    if (thread_type == 0){
                        result = new Rest.request().execute(Rest.CAMPUS_THREAD + thread_id, Rest.OSESS + Profile.sk, Rest.DELETE).get();
                    } else if (thread_type == 1){
                        result = new Rest.request().execute(Rest.GROUP_THREAD + thread_id, Rest.OSESS + Profile.sk, Rest.DELETE).get();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("delete thread", result.getResponse());
                
                if (result.getResponseCode() == 204){
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getString(R.string.The_thread_is_deleted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    refreshAfterPost();
                }
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
    
}
```

Both list.get(position).thumb_bitmap and list.get(position).RecBitmap are bitmaps, first is a smaller bitmap, the second one is a 1024x1024 large size bitmap image file.

And this is my xml file(campuswallrow) for the above CampusWallArrayAdapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" 
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_row_bg_state" >  
  
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivThumb"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/avatarframe" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="aa"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue0"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivThumb" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="bb"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivThumb"
    android:layout_below="@+id/display_name" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="cc"
    android:textColor="@color/dimgrey3"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivThumb"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImageBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    **android:id="@+id/ivImage"**
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bComment"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/dimgrey3"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_comment"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivImageBackground" />
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRedDot"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar_notification_nipple"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivImageBackground"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLike"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/dimgrey3"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_like"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivImageBackground"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bComment" />
   
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMore"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_context"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivImageBackground" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unreadcomment"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_unread_ribbon"
    android:gravity="center|right"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white1"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For the above xml file: @+id/ivImage is where I put the main bitmap image.

So am I doing correctly for the ArrayAdapter and ListView recycler? Can someone please give me some hints on how to make the scrolling performance better? Right now it is quite laggy.

Thank you!

Comment: A 1024x1024 bitmap is pretty large. I don't think the recycler is your problem. Are you sure you need such a large bitmap there?

Comment: hi, yes I do, at least for now, but isn't instagram or facebook has large size image too? I would assume they use very high quality pictures as well.

Comment: Not on their feed that I know of. Very few mobile devices can fit 1024x1024 on a screen. Instead, smaller thumbnails are shown on the feed and you can click to view the single image fullscreen. They're still fairly large images, but they look more on the order of 700px at least on my device. You should probably [use traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and see what is really causing slowdowns.